# ArcMap 10.6 make column values into child group layers

Tags: arcmap, layers

ArcMap 10.6

I have a Project point feature class with the location and name of each project. I want to make a Project layer containing (sub/child) group layers for each Project name. Then I can click individual locations on and off more easily than running selections.

Right now I can manually,

1. Right click the data frame and make a new group layer named Projects in the data frame
2. For each line the the Project point feature:

   2.1 Right click Project layer and create new Group Layer within, and rename this with the Project name

   2.2 Create a selection of that point in the Project feature class and move it into this correctly named new Group Layer.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Yes, but it will require some python. How many layers are in the group? Instead of creating a selection layer it would be best to copy the layer and apply a definition query. Selection layers are based on an OID set, over time OIDs can become out of sync if the data source is updated, especially shapefiles though I have seen this happen with SDE data, between creating the maps and exporting the PDFs the feature class was updated with a newer version, making all the maps *wrong* and it wasn't picked up until the document was printed.

Comment: @Michael Stimson Than you. I have saved the data into shape files from the database so it will not be affected by updates. There are 70 odd project in the group. i am up to some python but do not have the time to play with the very round about ways I have seen in examples so far. The commands do not seem well made for manipulating dataframe layouts.

Comment: This might be a bit left field but have you considered data driven pages? It might be a satisfactory alternative to lots of group layers, keeping your layout tidy. Shapefiles are the worst for static OID sets, if there is *any* edit the OIDs are no longer the same, it would be much better (safer) to use a definition query which data driven pages can update when changing from one project to another https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003p000000

Comment: @Son of a Beach Thanks. It might help, depending on how I set this out. Under spec machine for this job so I am looking for simple, low memory usage answers too. I think too many queries for display purposes is slowing me down too.

Comment: @Michael Stimson Please add your suggestion as an Answer so I can give you the tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the design of [data driven pages](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s90000003m000000) was intended to create a series of maps spanning numerous sites the concept of [page queries](https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Using_Page_Definition_Queries/00s90000003p000000/) can be leveraged to only display the features that have a matching identifier to the index layer. The index layer needs to have one row for each unique identifier covering the extent of the project area, in this case I'd make a buffer, dissolving by project name, to ensure that the entire area of the project and its children are completely covered.

As I stated in the comments shapefiles are the worst to create a FID set which is how *make layer from selected features* operates. If the shapefile is edited *in any way* the FID order will be altered and you will end up with a different set of features in your selection layer. File/personal geodatabases have static OIDs (object ID is a similar concept to feature/row ID) which means the features ID will never change for the lifetime of the row so a FID set generated from geodatabase objects are more tolerant but still, creating a layer from selected features should not be relied upon as a permanent arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the Split by Attributes tool for this?  Specify the ProjectName field as the tool's Split Field.

See:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm

You could create a new workspace for the output, and when it has completed, add all feature classes in the workspace to the map (ie, one layer for each project).